# How do I access a variable that's defined within an imported file?

Tags: python

My windows batch file:

```
python test.py
pause
```

test.py:

```
import test_import
print(greeting)
```

test_import.py:

```
greeting='hello world'
```

This isn't working. I'm getting an error message, saying 'greeting' is not defined. I'd like to show you the output, but I'm having trouble with that too.

What do I need to change withint test_import.py, so the variable is accessible within the main module?

Comment: `print(test_import.greeting)`

Answer (score 3):

change your test.py:

```py
import test_import
print(test_import.greeting)
```

or

```py
from test_import import greeting
print(greeting)
```